# jQuery Print - Show Preview before print

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, printing

I would like to print a portion of the page, that is a div. 
Also I need css files referred, so it will get printed as we see in the page.

> I tried to use [jQPrint](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqPrint) then [printThis](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) . But my IE7
>   browser was getting crashed when i click a button on second time. Not
>   sure what is the problem. My page has  lot of elements (100+ input
>   fields and 3 Grids)

***Finally, I followed this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm and implemented. Now no crash!***

**Now how can I show a print preview dialog before sending printer?**

*Something like this https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin, I tried this too but its not working :(*

Comment: If the print is supposed to look just like the page div why can't you just show the div in a modal with OK and back-button?

Comment: @Alex, I need to send the content to print. Before print, i want to see how it looks? Do you think showing model dialog will exactly same, the printer will print?

Comment: Well exactly replicating what the print will look like is nearly impossible but as far as format goes(A4 etc) it should not be a problem I think. You have the CSS for the print already which should give a pretty good preview of the print.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Alex. In fact, if you take a look at the print preview plugin you linked to, this is basically the approach it uses. The plugin creates a modal that contains an iFrame, and writes the relevant portions of the original page + the print CSS styles to that iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I did this same task in a prior job, and completed  y the following example. We set it up to where what ever part of the design we were sending to a printer, we would replicate the HTML, and create a dynamic page with that content, and then trigger the browser print dialog. If you want to do what you are asking, without a lot of "magic", this is a good way to handle it.